# Storing results in array of type double

Tags: java, arrays, double

I have a calculation that generates more than one result. The result are of type `double`. So I am storing the result in a `double []`.

```
private void calculateProducedEnergy() {
    for (Integer s: mWeatherProfile.getSunshine()) {
        for (Double w: mWeatherProfile.getWeatherConditions()) {
            mProducedEnergy = s * w * mPvSystem.getEfficiency() * mPvSystem.getPanelSurface();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language does this refer to?

Comment: @Codor it refers java.

Comment: You mean `mProducedEnergy` is now declared as a `double` so you only store the result of the last calculation; instead you would like to store _all_ of the numbers calculated in the loop?

Comment: `mProducedenergy` is a double and not an array of doubles. For storing all values, it should be `mProducedEnergy[i] = s * w * mPvSystem.getEfficiency() * mPvSystem.getPanelSurface(); `where i is just a counter and in each loop the i will increase in one (`i++`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this in two ways. If you wish to leave the variable `mProducedEnergy` as an array then

```
private void calculateProducedEnergy() {
 int counter = 0;
 for (Integer s: mWeatherProfile.getSunshine()) {
  for (Double w: mWeatherProfile.getWeatherConditions()) {
   mProducedEnergy[counter++] = s * w * mPvSystem.getEfficiency() * mPvSystem.getPanelSurface();
  }
 }
}
```

or change `mProducedEnergy` to a `List<> mProducedEnergy = new ArrayList<>();`

```
private void calculateProducedEnergy() {
 for (Integer s: mWeatherProfile.getSunshine()) {
  for (Double w: mWeatherProfile.getWeatherConditions()) {
   mProducedEnergy.add(s * w * mPvSystem.getEfficiency() * mPvSystem.getPanelSurface());
  }
 }
}
```